# Hosted service prevents app to start completely in .NET 6 without startup class

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

We have a hosted service that runs in the background all the time (while(true)) listening on a kafka topic for new events. But using the new way to write the program file without startup prevents for example the swagger to show when the hosted service is running. To prevent this according to the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) is to add the hosted service after this line:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
```

But this does not work. In .NET 5 you needed to do this by adding it after the startup in the program file:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
        {
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<VideosWatcher>();
        });
```

Using the method in .NET 5 works also in .NET 6.

This is the Program.cs:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddHostedService<KafkaService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

This is how our service looks, I have done a simple version but it has the same behaviour:

```
public class KafkaService : IHostedService
{
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        while (true)
        {
            string doSomething = "doSomething";
        }

    }
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same behaviour in .NET 6 using only the program file? Or is this a bug in .NET 6?

Comment: Can you please show how do you register your service and it's implementation.

Comment: And `KafkaService` implementation?

Comment: Added that one too now

Comment: You say it prevents Swagger from running. But you've not shown any of the setup necessary to get Swagger. Please make sure your example code is complete.

Comment: Edited with full code. To recreate you can just create a new project with the ASP.NET Core Web API template in visual studio and just add the hosted service above.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#startasync):

> `StartAsync` should be limited to short running tasks because hosted services are run sequentially, and no further services are started until `StartAsync` runs to completion.

Change to using `BackgroundService`:

```cs
class KafkaService1 : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            string doSomething = "doSomething";
        }
    }
}
```

Or repeat it's logic by starting a separate task:

```cs
public class KafkaService : IHostedService
{
    private CancellationTokenSource _cancellationTokenSource;
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);

        _ = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                string doSomething = "doSomething";
            }
        });
        
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    
    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not work for me, same behaviour. Have you tested this and it works for you?

Comment: @EResman I know that it's been a long time, but I finally fixed it =)

Comment: @alanh glad if it helped!